# Printing SQL Server Diagrams (from SQL Server Management Studio Express)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am having trouble printing my diagrams, I seem to be getting portions of the diagram blocked out, etc.  I've tried several different computers, printers, and databases, so it seems to be a problem with SSMS Express itself.

Is this just the way it is?

Are there any decent workarounds, or does anyone use a 3rd party product (preferably free or cheap) that can cleanly integrate with SQL Server?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Within the diagram, do a *Copy Diagram to Clipboard* from the edit menu, and then paste into a new Microsoft Word document.  From there, you can scale the drawing as you wish.

If you have a printer capable of printing to 11 x 17 paper, this works well.  I have been able to print schemas with 30 tables this way onto a single page, and the table objects are very nearly actual size.

Comment: I don't often use the database diagrams, but I'll use this option when I need to print one.  This definitely helps to overcome the incomplete "arrange tables" option in SSMS.  

"Arrange Tables" in SSMS does what it says -- arranges the tables -- but rather poorly.  It doesn't have options (or attempt) to use the fewest sheets possible or avoid page breaks in it's layout.

Thanks!

Comment: Start with a high zoom level within SQl Management studio, or else you'll have a low quality image when you paste into any other app.

Comment: @Dan: If you use *Copy Diagram To Clipboard*, you'll get the objects themselves, not images/bitmaps of the objects. So your zoom level won't matter.

Comment: @Robert: I tried pasting with the image at 10% zoom, and again at 150% resolution, and it does indeed make a difference. You won't notice if you only have a few tables, but if you copy-paste a large diagram at low zoom, it becomes illegible.

Comment: The Database Diagrams mechanism produces a *picture*.. and it often falls short of the quality needed for a word document (*ie Design Document*).
I've found that the best solution is to use Microsoft's Visio and reverse engineer the database into a visio diagram. The resulting *object* can then pasted easily into a word document - and it's readable!

Comment: You can also use Adobe Acrobat which has a 'Create PDF from cliboard' option (afer *Copy Diagram To Clipboard*). It's a little easier then to 'Fit to page' when printing which is most likely what you're wanting to do

Comment: for really big schemes it's better to paste into MS Excel, with Excel it is possible to print a big image on multiple A4 pages and the image will keep its quality

Comment: The snippet tool is an alternative.

Comment: @lena you are a LEGEND! None of these options worked for a very large schema, no matter what zoom level or print scale I used. It was always blurry until I tried excel. Whowuddathunkit?

Answer (score 16):

Right click in a space area then choose " ***Copy diagram to Clipboard*** ".

Go to "Paint" paste it then print it.

Answer (score 10):

Manual Solution: 
1- Open the diagram in SSMS
2- Right-Click and select 'View Page Breaks'
   (If your diagram is displayed across multiple pages, go to #3)
3- drag-and-drop all of you table items into one page space (you are done!)
4- Use the Zoom drop-down control to view your tables (i.e. Fit to, 10%, ... 100%)
5- save As Whatever name you want
6- Print your diagram, and it will fit to one page.

-Each one teach one,

Comment: Thanks Bill. Also another useful tip is you can drag the gradient lines   until your tables fit in one page, rather than moving the tables around!

Answer (score 8):

Use the page Setup and Print Scale

When you have your drawing, Go to File | Page Setup

From there, you can determine the paper size, orientation and ***most importantly*** the **Print Scale**

Once you have shown your page breaks, play with the print scale so that it fits on your chose pagesize.

[image]

then everyone who views the diagram can print directly from SMSS without needing to copy to clipboard and use other programs to print...

Comment: When combined with "view page breaks" and "recalculate page breaks," this is a winning solution.

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced related issues when printing multiple pages of SQL diagrams and finally found an acceptable solution that doesn’t involve copying the diagram elsewhere. My main issue being the auto-recalculation of the page breaks placement as you try to print.

First, in Page Setup, set your orientation / paper size / print scale

**1)** Enable View Page Breaks

**2)** Arrange the diagram in the pages like you want them (alternatively know that you can drag the blue page break lines also)

**3)** On the bottom-right corner of the last page (bottom-rightmost) place a text annotation with a bit of text (your company name, etc) and locate it somewhat close to that corner.

**4)** Try recalculating the page breaks again and see that they stay on the same place or close enough to where you want them.

**5)** Print & enjoy!

Note: I am using SSMS 2012 which I was hoping would finally solve this automatically but behaves like prior versions - at least this workaround lets me lay diagram properly on the printed page.

Comment: This is an amazing feature in SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help you or not, but I usually print to PDF via [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Suprised! Why would you want to export it to word or use CutePDF?

- Right click on the white background on the diagram choose View Page Breaks.
- From File choose print.

It works on my pc! :-]